# Is there a better way to create a mutable list of a given range?

Tags: list, kotlin, range

What I'm currently doing:

```
var idList = mutableListOf<Int>()

fun main() {
    for (number in 1000000..1999999) {
        idList.add(number)
    }

    println(idList[0]) //testing purposes
    println(idList[1]) //testing purposes
}
```

I feel like this is very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option I can think of right now is like this

```
val numbers = (1000000..1999999).toMutableList()
println(numbers.first())
println(numbers.last())
```